# Testing Flask web app with unittest POST Error 500

Tags: python, testing, flask, python-unittest

This is my test.py file:

```
import unittest, views, json

class FlaskTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

def setUp(self):
    self.app = views.app.test_client()

def test_index(self):
    rv = self.app.get('/')
    assert 'Hamptons Bank' in rv.data

def test_credit(self):
    response = self.app.post('/credit', data=json.dumps({
            'amount': '20',
            'account': '1'
        }), content_type='application/json')

    print response.data
    assert 'Deposit of 20 to account 1' in response.data


if __name__ == '__main__':
     unittest.main()
```

The test_index method works fine, but the self.app.post keeps returning (in print response.data):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.</p>
```

The method in my views.py is the following:

```
@app.route('/credit', methods=['POST'])
def credit_account():
  bank = Bank()

  amount = int(request.json["amount"])
  depositCommand = DepositCommand(find_account(request.json["account"]), amount)
  bank.execute(depositCommand)

  message = "Deposit of " + str(request.json["amount"]) + " to account "+str(request.json["account"])
  return message
```

What am I doing wrong?

This is my first time testing a Flask web app, so I am still a bit confused!

Thank you :-)

Comment: Is the last line of your `credit_account()` formatted wrong? The extra +" at the end?

Comment: is `request.json` a thing? I thought it was `request.form`

Comment: oops, sorry, the + appeared after the copy and paste, it is not like that in the method, just ignore it :-) edited the code

Comment: The method works, btw, the only problem is when testing, the web app is working fine

Comment: You should set `app.config['DEBUG'] = True` and `app.config['TESTING'] = True` on the application you're using. `request.json` is deprecated in favor of `request.get_json()` per the [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Request.json). You're sending `'1'` instead of `1` for `account` in your request and not converting it to an `int` before passing it to `find_account`, which seems like it could be problematic. json supports a few different native types, so using that to your advantage can make your code a little cleaner.

Comment: @jonafato app.config['TESTING'] = True did the trick! I really can't believe it was just this! Thank you!!!! If you want, post your comment as an answer, so that I can accept it :-) Cheers!

Comment: @LarissaLeite Posted, glad I could help.

Comment: As mentionned on the Flask documentation, the ``TESTING`` config flag disables the error catching during request handling. Hence, you get better error reports when performing test requests against the application. It has not to be considered as a workaround to get your test passing. Please provide the detailed error that you get in ``response.data`` when the ``TESTING`` flag is activated. This would be helpful to find the real reason of your problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

(From my comment above): when testing, you should set `app.config['DEBUG'] = True` and `app.config['TESTING'] = True`.